# Regular Expression jquery validation1

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can anybody share Regular Expression below example:

minimum 3 alphanumeric and then add only one '@' then again minimum 3 alphanumeric

example: rohit@tcs or himansu@infosys

Comment: Do you want to validate such strings specifically or you want to validate email format ?

Comment: i wand to validate such string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern that matches:

```
/\w{3,}@{1}\w{3,}$/
```

Comment: `\w` matches alphanumeric plus **underscore**.

Comment: This still matches the pattern he's calling for.

Comment: Thanks @Dream_Cap  it is working fine

Comment: If it works, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer, thank you :D

Comment: another query : this expression i need only one @ if i added more then one @ then it has been return true

<script>
alert(/\w{3,}@\w{3,}/.test('333@4449999@@@'));

</script>

Comment: I have updated the answer to include only one @. Edited it again, its /\w{3,}@{1}\w{3,}/

Comment: when i used "alert(/\w{3,}@\w{3,}/.test('333@4449999@@'));" then it should return false but it is returning true. please help

Comment: I updated the answer to account for the end of the string.